# how to append data coming from socket io to angular html

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I have a socket program which is listning and giving the log data.
Socket is sending correct data as in console i am getting the correct data.

Here is my code

```
export class RoboLogComponent implements OnInit {
dataToShow:any
@ViewChild('dataContainer') dataContainer : ElementRef;

loaddata(data:String) {
    this.dataContainer.nativeElement.innerHtml =data
}
ngOnInit():void{
console.log("I am triggering")
let socket=io('http://localhost:9999')
socket.on('send-log-data',function(data){
    console.log(data) //here it is displaying correct value emitted from socket
    this.dataContainer.nativeElement.innerHtml =data //but is not getting reflected
})
}
}
```

In html I have defined it to append.

```
<div #dataContainer></div>
```

Here from socket data is coming properly but it is not getting reflected to ui.
In console it is prinitng correct value.

Actually my use case is one of my backend code generating log in html format continuously and i need to display the log in web ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got answered for my question after doing lots of research .
The soution i came with

```
export class RoboLogComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit,OnDestroy {
 dataToShow:string="lets see if i am coming"
 socket:any

loaddata(data:any) {
    console.log("chcking")
    this.htmlToadd =this.htmlToadd+"<br>"+data
}
ngOnInit():void{
    this._labService.streamLogs().subscribe(data => 
this.socket=io('http://localhost:9999')
}


ngAfterViewInit(){
this.socket.on('send-log-data',function(data){
                this.loaddata(data)                
}.bind(this))
}
 ngOnDestroy(){
this.socket.disconnect()
}

}
```

And in html file just add

```
<div class="abc" [innerHtml]="htmlToadd | sanitizeHtml" *ngIf='htmlToadd'></div>
```

Here sanitizeHtml pipe used just to bypass security check of dynamically loaded html content.