# How to display logs to UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http

I have configured  set of operation in UI and when user start the operation it call in backend some python script.I need to display the logs to UI which is generated by python script.I have implemented somehow in [how to append data coming from socket io to angular html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45039776/how-to-append-data-coming-from-socket-io-to-angular-html) using socket-io.

I wanted to know is there anyway to show continuous logs without using socket-io.
I am using node js as backend and angular as frontend.

Comment: the server either needs some way to stream data to the client (socket.io) ((push)) or the client needs to periodically check to see if there is new data available on the server ((pull)).  There are, of course, other libraries similar to socket.io, or you could write your own push libraries, but this isn't something angular packages....

Answer (score 1):

One way is the (optional) underlay of socket.io: [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)

Another way is [HTML5 Server-Sent Events (SSE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events).
There is [a tutorial on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp)

---

WebSocket is actually a TCP link, which is perfect for rapid two direction communications, while SSE is transmission like terminal or what, which should be better for your situation (log to front end).